# How to read a std::wstring written in linux into windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux, cross-platform, wstring

We have a program which runs on Windows and Linux. It writes out std::wstrings in binary to a file. We need to be able to read in files written from linux into windows. We write out strings as a list of wchar_t. On linux each wchar_t occupies 4 bytes. On Windows each wchar_t occupies 2 bytes.

When reading the file written by linux into Windows how can one take the four byte wchar_t and put it into the 2 byte wchar_t?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net) to easily convert the file from UTF-32 to UTF-16:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utf8.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::ifstream file("source.txt");
    std::string   intermediate;
    std::wstring  result;

    utf8::utf32to8(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
                   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                   std::back_inserter(intermediate));

    utf8::utf8to16(intermediate.begin(),
                   intermediate.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(result));

}
```

Unfortunately there is no `utf8::utf32to16`, though perhaps there should be.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Linux code is writing out in UTF-32 format, you'll have to write some code to convert the string to UTF-16 which is the Unicode encoding used on Windows.  wstring can't help you with this.  Once you have converted to UTF-16, you can store in a wstring on Windows using wchar_t.

Comment: The conversion code from UTF-32 to UTF-16 [doesn't look difficult](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).